# QR Code with VCards are not working in Blackberry

Tags: php, blackberry, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I generate QR code of a VCard on my site, & now when I read it, it works on Nokia, and Iphone, but it is not working on Black Berry.

Bellow is my simple VCard template that I created QRCode of :

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:rahman;sohail;;Mr
FN:Sohail Rahman
END:VCARD

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How are you reading the QR code?

Comment: on Black Berry I read the QR code from the screen by the QR code scanner. and shows me the exact string instead of the VCard.

Comment: is the "QR code scanner" a 3rd party application?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put linebreaks in the code for it to be read properly.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:rahman;sohail;;Mr
FN:Sohail Rahman
END:VCARD
```

If you're using HTML encoding, the "carriage return" character is %0D

Comment: Actually line breaks are there already, I am sorry about my question formatting, the SO remove the line breaks when I save them, but in my code I used \n to do the new line.

Comment: What are you using to encode it? Do you have a sample of the QR code?

Comment: Well, the one I did is not working on BB, so I tried for some more standard samples and here is the one I posted the VCARD in this question from : http://www.moongate.ro/en/products/qr_code-vcard/vCard?c=iNncy1#error 
try this on BB, and it won't work

Comment: The raw text from that seems fine - but the encoder may have a problem. What happens if you scan in this code - http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chld=L&choe=UTF-8&chl=BEGIN%3AVCARD%0AN%3ASohail+Rahman%0AEND%3AVCARD
Generated from http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/

Comment: Its not working, both of the links, the VCard QRCODE shows the original text (like BEGIN VCARD...) and not the VCARD.

Comment: Which QR scanner are you using on BlackBerry? It may be faulty.

Comment: its called QR Code Scanner Pro

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the QR code scanner inside the BlackBerry messenger application. This will only read QR codes which are in BBM format which supports only a few fields: PIN, URL and telephone number.

VCARD information is not supported in BBM QR codes.

Comment: no, its QR CODE application and its called QR Code Scanner Pro

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding with different [error correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction) settings. Maybe the BB decoder can't handle the one you are using.